# Как сделать чтобы секции LP и картинки которые в них грузились после шапки?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, оптимизация, загрузка, оптимизация-сайтов

Как сделать чтобы секции LP и картинки которые в них грузились после шапки?

Есть лендинг, есть к нему прелоадер типа:

**html**

```
<div id="loader">
   <div id="loaderInner"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).**load**(function() {
    $("#loaderInner").fadeOut(); 
    $("#loader").delay(400).fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

*// после идет*

```
$(function() {

*//много другого кода =)*

})
```

Прелоадер выключаетя только после того как весь контент загружен, а не только шапка, менял window в выборке на класс шапки - ноль эффекта, и load вообще не наступает не убирает анимацию прелоадера, работает только если заменить на ready.
ccылка на весь js код: http://codepen.io/junior-web-dev/pen/WpWKoN?editors=1010

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Пример кода?

Comment: или как то очередью загрузки изображений можно управлять? чтоб в шапке фон первым грузился, а потом все остальные картинки на странице)

Comment: А <div id="loader"> нельзя поставить после шапки в html? И потом <element onload="myFunction"></element>